# Extracting all possible polygons from set of different types of geometrical elements

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, extract, polygonize, borders

I have an input, a set of different types of 2D geometrical elements with all its attributes (arcs, circles, lines, polylines, rectangles, polygons..). These elements can be connected end to end, overlapping, intersecting.

I want to extract all possible polygons formed from this set of elements, including the outermost polygons which can be a superset of inner polygons.
(I need to integrate this in a C# .Net application, where I will extract all polygons and be able to give Color-Fill to any of those polygons)

[image]

I need to extract all the inner (green) and outer(red) polygons.

I would like to know if there is an existing implementation available for this. Or if any combination of existing solutions would provide a required output.

If there are no solutions available, how could I develop a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

For a conceptual solution using QGIS, you can use the following procedure:

1. [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#dissolve) all polygons
2. Convert [polygons to lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#polygons-to-lines)
3. Use [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?#split-with-lines): split polygons from step 1 with lines from step 2.

*left:before ; right: after*
[image]